# Can not trace react-hook callstack in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, react-hooks

I try to trace an error in Chrome XHR network panel

[image]

When I hover over VM1716:1

I saw something like this

[image]

I can see the XHR is triggered by `@useUser.js:13`. It is already helpful, but it is even more helpful to know who trigger `@useUser.js:13`. Clearly, some react component should trigger the hook, but I fail to track the component

Why that happens how can I know which component triggers the hook

Same thing in console panel, no hint where the hook is invoked